# Adding a shipping disclaimer to checkout

Tags: shipping

Very new to Magento (currently switching over from Opencart).
The business I work for typically posts items over $50 for free to most destinations within Australia, but we currently have a disclaimer stating that for large or particularly bulky items, as well as for remote destinations, freight may be charged on these and the customer will be contacted within two business days specifying as much. 
We are a musical instrument store and so shipping a piano or drum kit for free to the middle of the Australian desert (for example) could easily see us lose any profit and even lose money on the sale if we don't have such a disclaimer in place.
Perhaps I have missed something as I have been setting up the new cart, but I can't see an easy way to include this in the checkout procedure. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Scott

Comment: As a quick comment go search for available.phtml. This will give you a start point. You can add messages in here. You will obviously need to flush this out but hopefully it helps just a little ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in checkout terms and conditions functionality.  From admin navigate to `sales->terms and conditions` and create a relevant entry.  The checkbox text is what is displayed next to the checkbox you need to tick to agree and the content is the main text body.

Once done navigate to `system->configuration->checkout->checkout options` and set `enable terms and conditions` to `yes`.  Assuming your theme allows the terms and conditions to be shown, they will now be visible on the checkout and you will be required to agree to them before you can place an order.

Comment: No problems, if this answer helped you can you mark it as correct?

Comment: Certainly - I hope I have done that for you now.
And once again, thank you!